# icanhaz.js issues

Tags: jquery, icanhaz.js

I am just trying to display a list of items inside an Object I am pulling in with an AJAX call.  I would like to display it with icanhaz.js template.

HTML:

```
<script id="trending" type="text/html">
      <li>
        <p>Name: {{ Trending.name }}</p>
      </li>
  </script>

<ul id="trending" class="span12">
    <li>Trending</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
            dataType : 'jsonp',
            url      : 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/sxsw_trending/sxsw_trending.json',
            jsonp : "callback",
            jsonpCallback: "sxswTrending",
                success  : function (data) {
                            console.log(data.Trending);
                                var trendingArr = [];
                                         var trending;
                                         trending = ich.trending(data);
                                         $('#trending').append(trending);       

                                for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
                                         var trending;
                                         trending = ich.trending(data[i]);
                                         $('#trending').append(trending);

                                         trendingArr.push(data[i]);
                                }

               }

    });

});
```

The data I am pulling in looks like this:
sxswTrending({"Restaurants":[],"Bars":[],"Trending":[{"id":"43582f80f964a520dd281fe3","name":"Whole Foods Market","hereNow":12},{"id":"440da323f964a52092301fe3","name":"Austin Convention Center","hereNow":6}]})

Not sure where my hang up is, I am just trying to display the name in each object called Trending.

I have also put it up on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xtian/W6mMu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified your code, to illustrate how to fix it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        dataType      : 'jsonp',
        url           : 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/sxsw_trending/sxsw_trending.json',
        jsonpCallback : 'sxswTrending',
        success  : function(data) {      
                     for (var i = 0; i < data.Trending.length; i++) {
                        var trending = ich.trending(data.Trending[i]);
                           $('#trending').append(trending);
                     }
                   }                                    
    });
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/43WDa/